# PHP/SQL - Searching a DB in a different language

Tags: php, sql, search, translate

I have a simple product search on my site like so:

```
$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(product_name) AGAINST(?)";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$resultCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if($resultCount > 0){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        //get search results
    }
}
```

My site is all in English and my DB is all in English, but according to my analytics we had someone from Portugal search in Portuguese on the Site but they didn't get any results even though there was results there for the translated version of what they searched for.

Is there anyway to get around this or detect the language they are inputting and translate it without having to pay for Google Translate or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose he was searched with portuguese like this: `óà`

You can:

1. Add translations of your content and search in them
2. Convert non-English letters to English and then search.

Comment: I don't think just changing the letters will work I'd need a full translation of my product names. What I really need is an alternative (not paid) to Google translate API so that I can just add the translations to another column when I'm adding new products to the DB rather than having to manually translate them. This might be a bit awkward though if I have to store a translation in the DB for every language. What I'd really like is to be able to detect the language used to search and translate that and then search my existing DB for that translation.

Comment: You can store translations in different columns for example: text_es, text_de, text_pt and search in them. You can also create one table for all translations: text, language and search in it. If you use Translations API on each request it can be slow. You can run translations for all texts and store them in the database. after that search in the database. You can search for free Google alternative